# Translate this Tableau Calculation to DAX PBI Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, tableau-api, measure

I have this Tableau calculation:

```
if [wlb_metric_name]='Count at Shift End'
and date([Interval_end_Datetime_ET]) = [Shift End Time]
and date([Shift Start Datetime])= [Overnight Shift Start Date]
and [Date] = Date([Interval_Start_Datetime_ET])
and [Date] = [Shift End Time]
then [wlb_metric_value] else 0 end
)/
COUNT(
if [wlb_metric_name]='Count at Shift End'
and date([Interval_end_Datetime_ET]) = [Shift End Time]
and date([Shift Start Datetime])= [Overnight Shift Start Date]
and [Date] = Date([Interval_Start_Datetime_ET])
and [Date] = [Shift End Time]
then [wlb_metric_value] else null end
),0)
```

And I need to convert this to PBI Dax Measure. This is the code that I tried but apparently it is incorrect

```
IF(
    ISBLANK(SUMX(
        FILTER(
            'Workload Balancing Fact',
            [wlb_metric_name] = "Count at Shift End"
                && [Interval_end_Datetime_ET].[Date] = [Shift End Time]
                && [Shift Start Datetime].[Date] = [Overnight Shift Start Date]
                && [Date] = [Interval_Start_Datetime_ET].[Date]
                && [Date] = [Overnight Shift Start Date].[Date]
        ),
        [wlb_metric_value]
    ) / COUNTX(
        FILTER(
            'Workload Balancing Fact',
            [wlb_metric_name] = "Count at Shift End"
                && [Interval_end_Datetime_ET].[Date] = [Shift End Time]
                && [Shift Start Datetime].[Date] = [Overnight Shift Start Date]
                && [Date] = [Interval_Start_Datetime_ET].[Date]
                && [Date] = [Overnight Shift Start Date]
        ),
        [wlb_metric_value]
    )),
    0,
    SUMX(
        FILTER(
            'Workload Balancing Fact',
            [wlb_metric_name] = "Count at Shift End"
                && [Interval_end_Datetime_ET].[Date] = [Shift End Time]
                && [Shift Start Datetime].[Date] = [Overnight Shift Start Date]
                && [Date] = [Interval_Start_Datetime_ET].[Date]
                && [Date] = [Overnight Shift Start Date]
        ),
        [wlb_metric_value]
    ) / COUNTX(
        FILTER(
            'Workload Balancing Fact',
            [wlb_metric_name] = "Count at Shift End"
                && [Interval_end_Datetime_ET].[Date] = [Shift End Time]
                && [Shift Start Datetime].[Date] = [Overnight Shift Start Date]
                && [Date] = [Interval_Start_Datetime_ET].[Date]
                && [Date] = [Shift End Time]
        ),
        [wlb_metric_value]
    )
)
```

I have been wracking my brains on where I am doing this calculation incorrectly. I am not getting an error, which is technically worse. Please help!

Comment: What is `[wlb_metric_value]`? Column or measure? If measure, can you share its Dax expression.

Comment: It is hard to see above which are columns and which are measures. Are these measures?
`[Shift End Time]`, `[Overnight Shift Start Date]`, `[Date]`

Comment: They are all columns.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `.[Date]` (date hierarchy) - so try omitting those.

Here is a cleaned-up version of your expression:

```
Your Measure = 
  var factFilter = FILTER(
    'Workload Balancing Fact',
    [wlb_metric_name] = "Count at Shift End"
        && [Interval_end_Datetime_ET] = [Shift End Time]
        && [Shift Start Datetime] = [Overnight Shift Start Date]
        && [Date] = [Interval_Start_Datetime_ET]
        && [Date] = [Shift End Time]
  )
  var sumValue = SUMX(factFilter, [wlb_metric_value])
  var cntValue = COUNTX(factFilter, [wlb_metric_value])

  RETURN DIVIDE(sumValue, cntValue, 0)
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?